# Trouble with laravel (NotFoundHttpException)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error.

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

I have a login view with a form, I validate the form with ajax, without a problem. When I try to return a view once I've successfuly logged in.

```
if ($validation->fails()){
    return Response::json(array( 'success' => false, 'errors' => $validation->getMessageBag()->toArray() ));
}else if(Auth::attempt($loginData)){
            $usuario=Usuario::find(Input::get('rut'));
            return View::make('logged')->with(array('nombre' => $usuario->primer_nombre.' '.$usuario->apellido_paterno.' '.$usuario->apellido_materno,
                                                'rut' => $usuario->id_usuario,
                                                'tipo' => $usuario->id_tipo)); 
}else{ return Response::json(array( 'exists' => false, 'message' => 'El usuario no existe o la contraseña es inválida.' )); }
```

I guess the problem is in the last *else* statement,I get an *404* error.

Comment: Can you show use the relevant routes please?

Answer (score 0):

This is the route:

```
Route::post('ingresar','LoginController@login');
```

The action on the form is `ingresar` then I use the login method in `LoginController`

```
public function login(){

    if(Request::ajax()){            
        //validamos el formulario.
        $loginData = array(
            'id_usuario'       =>    Input::get('rut'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );              
        $rules = array(
            'rut'   => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',

        );              
        $messages = array(
            'required'          => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio.',
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validation->fails()){
             return Response::json(array(
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validation->getMessageBag()->toArray()
            )); 
        }else if(Auth::attempt($loginData)){
            $usuario=Usuario::find(Input::get('rut'));
            return View::make('logged')->with(array('nombre' => $usuario->primer_nombre.' '.$usuario->apellido_paterno.' '.$usuario->apellido_materno,
                                                'rut' => $usuario->id_usuario,
                                                'tipo' => $usuario->id_tipo));
        }else{
            return Response::json(array(
                'exists' => false,
                'message' => 'El usuario no existe o la contraseña es inválida.'
            )); 
        }
    }

}
```